# Docker service freezes with no logs

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have a consumer written in Go which consumes messages from RabbitMQ then connects two different DBs and does some work.
I am using `docker-compose` to run my consumer. Generally it works fine.

But sometimes it so happens that the `docker logs <container_id>` command shows nothing and the RabbitMQ UI shows that no consumers are running on the queue. All this happens while the Docker container is still up. I then just stop and start the container and everything goes normal.

I am not able to debug this. Has anyone encountered this before or has an idea about this issue?

Comment: Are you using docker-on-windows?

Comment: are closing the rabbitmq channel in defer? you can try strategies like reconnect to rabbitmq if connection not active

Comment: Maybe some investigation of the running container with `docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh` helps.

Comment: @MAshrafulA yes i am closing channel in defer , and i am also reconnecting to rabbit mq if the channel connection gets closed unexpectedly / connection not active . Thanks

Comment: @RoBeaToZ can you please elaborate a bit as i am still a begineer with docker. Thanks

Comment: @Manmohan_singh . using it on linux . Thanks

Comment: `docker exec` allows you to execute arbitrary commands, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/. With the options `-it` and the command `/bin/sh` you will get a shell and will be able to investigate your container with commands like `ls -l`, `cat /some/file.txt`, etc.

Comment: Facing same with dockerized setup involving ELK stack + filesbeat. Unable to read `docker serives logs -f filebeats-service` doesn't output anything. Seems there is an unresolved [bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41733). Other [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386360/where-to-check-for-docker-service-logs).