# Where to check for docker service logs?

Tags: docker, service, docker-swarm

I have one service, which stuck somewhere, I don't know how to find the reason.

```
$ docker stack services worker_bleeding
ID                  NAME                         MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                               PORTS
eb6b7s242fi5        worker_bleeding_worker   replicated          0/1                 docker-hub/py:bleeding
```

When I check the status of the service, it shows Starting....

```
$ docker service ps worker_bleeding_worker
ID                  NAME                               IMAGE                                                               NODE                                     DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
1qyn5iyo0kei        worker_bleeding_worker.1       docker-hub/py:bleeding   worker12.node   Running             Starting 31 hours ago
```

I tried to see `docker service logs` but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Facing same with dockerized setup involving ELK stack + filesbeat. Unable to read `docker serives logs -f filebeats-service` doesn't output anything. Seems there is an unresolved [bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41733). Other [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830108/docker-service-freezes-with-no-logs).

Answer (score 3):

Service tasks where the current state hasn't reached running won't have had an opportunity to log anything yet.

Typically `docker service ps <service> --no-trunc` can show error messages for any tasks that actually do fail.

Otherwise `docker service inspect <service>` might have some diagnostics.

The lack of an outright timout or failure of somekind is concerning.

Comment: ```$ docker service ps wbworker_bleeding_wbworker --no-trunc

ID                          NAME                               IMAGE                                                                                                                                       NODE                                     DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
1qyn5iyo0keiu0qijcjyiqvzw   worker_bleeding_worker.1       docker-hub/py:bleeding@sha256:f295be9386f8a9c8896d747b8f9e3b72c047c4446621defb53c49efc93281bb3   worker-node   Running             Starting 2 days ago```

Comment: This is `--no-trunc` response. It doesn't show anything :(

Comment: I tried with `inspect` too, but its not giving any logs.